# Setting Object State in Context

Tags: react-native, react-context, react-native-state

I am new to React and React Native and am trying to understand some things. I am hoping someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong here. I have an object that I am attempting to set the value of independent variables with onChangeText. That object handles the data through

```
const { data, updateUserDetails} = useContext(MembershipContext);
```

**In the form field**

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    placeholder="First Name"
    value={data.userDetails.fname}
    onChangeText={(val) => updateUserDetails('fname', val)}
/>
```

**And in the Context file**

```
const updateUserDetails = (field, val) => {
    setUserDetails([
        ...userDetails.field, val
    ]);
};
```

**I am trying to update this state**

```
const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
    fname: '',
    lname: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    zip: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    password: '',
});
```

I hope that this is enough to analyze. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I think your problem is on how you call `setUserDetails`. Try to replace it with:

```
const updateUserDetails = (field, val) => {
    setUserDetails({
        ...userDetails, [field]: val
    });
};
```

And problem should be solved.

Comment: Awesome! That worked beautifully. I was sooo close :) Thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Yes, I also had some problem to undestand how to set state object. It's a little bit tricky (maybe react should simplify...). Have a nice day :)